# Aggregate and group with case when statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a query against a table that contains daily payroll data for employees at different locations.  I need to be able to get a count of employee ids that have greater than 30 paid hours in a week and a count of employee ids that have less than 20 for the same week.  I've tried this with no luck:

```
select
[WEEKENDING],
[LOCATION],
sum(case when [PAID_HOURS] > 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [COUNT_OVER_30],
sum(case when [PAID_HOURS] < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [COUNT_UNDER_20]
from mydb.payroll
group by [WEEKENDING],[LOCATION]
```

This is the source table:

[image: Source table]

Here is the desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Please don't use images, use table markdown text

Comment: Case is an expression **not** a statement

Comment: As the source data doesn't have columns named `weekending` or `location`, seems like you have an obvious place to start.

Comment: What isn't working with your current query?

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.

Comment: Do your weeks really end on a Tuesday? The first thing you need to do is map your dates to weeks and week-ending dates - possibly using a combination of `DATE_BUCKET()` and `DATEADD()`. You then need to sum the hours, grouped by date, location, and employee. That can all be wrapped up in a subquery or CTE and fed into your final query to calculate your counts.

Comment: @T N, your suggestion did the trick, I ended up using a CTE to sum the daily hours into a week and then referencing that CTE in my case expression to get the counts!  Thanks!  Can you submit as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: And yes, unfortunately it does run TU-MO.  HAHA

Comment: @ZRaptor - Glad you got your answer. However, without usable schema and data (text or markdown table that I can cut and paste into a fiddle - not an image), it is not worth my time to manually transcribe the data and prepare a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right idea, but maybe in the wrong order.
First group by `EMPID, WEEKENDING, FACILITY` to sum the number of hours per employee, then count the `EMPID`s for each case.
So, something like:

```
SELECT WEEKENDING, FACILITY,
    SUM( CASE WHEN WORKED_HOURS > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS WH30,
    SUM( CASE WHEN WORKED_HOURS < 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS WH20,
SELECT W, EMPID, FACILITY, SUM(WORKED_HOURS) AS WH
FROM (
    SELECT EMPID, WEEKENDING, FACILITY, 
        SUM(WORKED_HOURS) AS WORKED_HOURS
    FROM Wherever
    GROUP BY EMPID, WEEKENDING, FACILITY
) T
GROUP BY W, FACILITY
```

Comment: Looks like the above needs a syntax check.